# how to set local variable for transaction in jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm working on a project in whose database I need to initialize a session variable. If I work directly with sql, the initialization is done with `SET` statement

```
set local app.user_id to "0000";
```

I try to initialize it with `Connection#setClientInfo()` but failed

```
try(Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    boolean isAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
    try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("app.user_id", "0000");

        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.setClientInfo(properties);

        String query = "insert into positions (name, description) values (?, ?)";

        try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, position.getName());
            statement.setString(2, position.getDescription());

            statement.executeUpdate();
        }

        connection.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        connection.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        connection.setAutoCommit(isAutoCommit);
    }
}
```

I get `PSQLException` (insert query is dependent on parameter and it does not pass)

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "app.user_id"
```

If I use `PreparedStatement` I get `PSQLException` with message *ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"*

```
try(Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    boolean isAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("set local app.user_id to ?")) {
            statement.setString(1, "0000");
            statement.execute();
        }

        String query = "insert into positions (name, description) values (?, ?)";

        try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, position.getName());
            statement.setString(2, position.getDescription());

            statement.executeUpdate();
        }

        connection.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        connection.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        connection.setAutoCommit(isAutoCommit);
    }
}
```

The only way to go through is by directly executing the query with fixed values. But in doing so, I am forced to use a concatenation to build the query. And I do not want to do it.

```
try(Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    boolean isAutoCommit = connection.getAutoCommit();
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try(Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            statement.execute("set local app.user_id to 0000");
        }

        String query = "insert into positions (name, description) values (?, ?)";

        try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
            statement.setString(1, position.getName());
            statement.setString(2, position.getDescription());

            statement.executeUpdate();
        }

        connection.commit();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        connection.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        connection.setAutoCommit(isAutoCommit);
    }
}
```

What is the right way to initialize such parameters?
I use PostgreSQL 11, JDBC 4.2 (with driver 42.2.5) and DBCP 2.5

***Edit***

I did it by calling `set_config`.

```
try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select set_config(?, ?, true)")) {
    statement.setString(1, "app.user_id");
    statement.setString(2, "0000");

    statement.execute();
}
```

But the question remains. How to call `SET` in `JDBC`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this on the `DataSource` not the `Connection`.

In `postgresql` the only way I know of would be to downconvert.  Something like:

```
DataSource myDS = getDataSource();
if (DataSource instanceof BaseDataSource.class) {
    BaseDataSource pgDS = (BaseDataSource) myDS;   // expose setProperty method
    pgDS.setProperty("app.user_id", "0000");
}
```

where you place this in your application obviously depends upon many details not presented in your question.

Comment: I use `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`